# Unnable to connect Qt signal to a custom class member function

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals

I'm currently working in a Qt project and I don't have no much experience on Qt yet, so I'm coding from time to time some tests each time I'm stuck on something that I don't understand.

The last test code I've been working on is a [`QNetworkRequest`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkrequest.html) wrapper to store network requests like this:

```
std::list<R> requests;
QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://awesome/web/api"));
requests.emplace_back(NetworkAccessManager.get(request), myCallback);
```

The object `R` looks like the lines below:

**First attempt**

---

```
struct R
{
    R(QNetworkRequest *const r, void (*cb)(QNetworkRequest *)) :
        m_r(r),
        m_cb(cb)
    {
        if (m_r)
        {
            // Error on line below
            QObject::connect(m_r, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, &R::reply);
        }
    }

private:

    void reply() { m_cb(m_r); }

    QNetworkRequest *const m_r;
    void (*m_cb)(QNetworkRequest *);
};
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
no matching function for call to 'QObject::connect(QNetworkRequest* const&, void (QNetworkReply::*)(), R* const, void (R::*)())'
         QObject::connect(m_r, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, &R::reply);
```

I don't understand why the connection isn't correct, I'm pretty sure about doing similar connections before.

At first I was suspecting that the error is releated to the fact that `R` isn't a `QObject`, so I made the following change:

**Second attempt**

---

```
struct R
    : public QObject // <-- New!
{
    Q_OBJECT // <-- New!
    R(QNetworkRequest *const r, void (*cb)(QNetworkRequest *)) :
        m_r(r),
        m_cb(cb)
    {
        if (m_r)
        {
            // Error on line below
            QObject::connect(m_r, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, &R::reply);
        }
    }

private:

    void reply() { m_cb(m_r); }

    QNetworkRequest *const m_r;
    void (*m_cb)(QNetworkRequest *);
};
```

This change produces even more compilation errors:

```
no matching function for call to 'R::connect(QNetworkRequest* const&, void (QNetworkReply::*)(), R* const, void (R::*)())'
         QObject::connect(m_r, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, &R::reply);

invalid use of incomplete type 'struct QtPrivate::QEnableIf<false, QMetaObject::Connection>'

declaration of 'struct QtPrivate::QEnableIf<false, QMetaObject::Connection>'
 template <bool B, typename T = void> struct QEnableIf;
```

So I continued my efforts to fix the compiler errors (pretty blindly due to my lack of experience on Qt), my next try consists in transforming the method `R::reply()` into a slot:

**Third attempt**

---

```
struct R
    : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    R(QNetworkRequest *const r, void (*cb)(QNetworkRequest *)) :
        m_r(r),
        m_cb(cb)
    {
        if (m_r)
        {
            // Error on line below
            QObject::connect(m_r, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, &R::reply);
        }
    }

private slots: // <-- New!
    void reply() { m_cb(m_r); }
private:
    QNetworkRequest *const m_r;
    void (*m_cb)(QNetworkRequest *);
};
```

This doesn't fix the problem at all, in fact, it produces exactly the same errors as the previous version.

So my last attempt to fix the problem is to use the Qt macros on the `connect` instruction:

**Last attempt**

---

```
struct R
    : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    R(QNetworkRequest *const r, void (*cb)(QNetworkRequest *)) :
        m_r(r),
        m_cb(cb)
    {
        if (m_r)
        {
            // Error on line below
            QObject::connect(m_r, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(reply()));
        }
    }

private slots:
    void reply() { m_cb(m_r); }
private:
    QNetworkRequest *const m_r;
    void (*m_cb)(QNetworkRequest *);
};
```

Which reports the following errors:

```
no matching function for call to 'R::connect(QNetworkRequest* const&, const char*, R* const, const char*)'
         QObject::connect(m_r, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(reply()));

no type named 'Object' in 'struct QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<const char*>'

invalid use of incomplete type 'struct QtPrivate::QEnableIf<false, QMetaObject::Connection>'
```

Finally, I think that is the time of stop guessing and start to ask for help:

- What I'm doing wrong on my first attempt? I'm pretty sure that is possible to connect Qt signals with class methods of classes unrelated with QObject, I'm wrong?
- What's wrong on the other attempts? They complained about different things than the first one.
- Why in the last attempt the `connect` signature uses `const char*`, the macros `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` are converting the code into characters?
- Some guidelines in order to avoid problems like this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hm, but `QNetworkRequest` is not a QObject at all - you cannot "connect" its signals, because there is none. You can establish connection only between `QObjects`.

Comment: did you pass R through the moc and compiled and linked in the output after each step?

Comment: Also you're trying to connect a signal of `QNetworkReply` in an object of type `QNetworkRequest`.

Comment: @Oktalist you found the error! after changing classes according to your clue, I was able to compile. I wonder why the error messages are that unclear.

Comment: The first error wasn't too bad. Properly deciphered it says no matching function for call with first argument being pointer to `QNetworkRequest` and second argument being pointer to member function of `QNetworkReply`. The referral to `QEnableIf` in the other errors suggests a SFINAE condition is not being fulfilled, with hindsight this is probably because `m_r` doesn't point to a `QObject`. I wonder which compiler you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use [`QNetworkAccessManager`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) because this, unlike `QNetworkRequest`, inherits from `QObject` and has a `finished` signal, thus allowing you to connect to it.

But to answer your first question:

You have to use the `Q_OBJECT` macro and to inherit from `QObject` in order to be able to use the signals&slots mechanism.

Guideline to avoid similar problems:

The documentation of [`QNetworkRequest`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkrequest.html) doesn't state anything about a `finished` slot, nor about inheriting from `QObject` which is necessary in order to use signals&slots.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to connect a signal of the class `QNetworkReply` coming from an object of unrelated class `QNetworkRequest`.

Additionally, `QNetworkRequest` doesn't inherit from `QObject`.

> Why in the last attempt the `connect` signature uses `const char*`, the macros `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` are converting the code into characters?

Yes, the `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros expand to C-style strings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I found this solution elsewhere in an application and it works.

Instead of:
`QObject::connect(m_r, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, &R::reply);`

Write:
`QObject::connect(m_r, &QNetworkReply::finished, [=](){this->reply();});`